# Edit JSON item from file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
import json

with open("prefix.json", 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

def changeprefix(id, prefix):
    global data
    if not id in data:
        json.dump(data, open("prefix.json", "w"), indent = 4)
        data[id] = prefix
    else:
        # Code to edit existing item

changeprefix("6", "?")
```

It opens a file named `prefix.json` and I want to be able to edit an existing item, for example:

```
{
    "item": "234"
}
```

How can I change `item` to something else, for example to `text here`, then save the file?

Comment: `data["item"] = "text here"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is assign to `data["item"]` and then write all of `data` into `prefix.json`!

```py
data["item"] = "text here"
with open("prefix.json", "w") as f: # Makes sure to close the file
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```